# buscar un archivo dentro de otro e imprimir las coincidencias

Tags: bash, shell, join, diff

tengo dos archivos
archivo 1

```
1,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,SRR9831337
1,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,SRR9831339
121,7,6,8,8,6,37,1,SRR9831336
129,90,24,155,189,117,244,66,H38
4,1,2,12,3,2,5,3,AW73
599,70,80,30,33,45,240,68,AW71
689,8,6,8,6,1,37,1,AW72
876,125,1,1,1,3,1,3,SRR9831338
ST,abcZ,bglA,cat,dapE,dat,ldh,lhkA,Sample
```

Archivo2

```
1,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,CC1,I,
121,7,6,8,8,6,37,1,CC121,II,
129,90,24,155,189,117,244,66,ST129,L.,welshimeri
4,1,2,12,3,2,5,3,CC4,I,
599,70,80,30,33,45,240,68,ST599,L.,innocua
689,8,6,8,6,1,37,1,CC689,II,
876,125,1,1,1,3,1,3,CC1,I,
ST,abcZ,bglA,cat,dapE,dat,ldh,lhkA,CC,Lineage,
```

Como puedo hacer para que las coincidencias se impriman en un solo archivo?

Ya he intentado con:

```
grep -f archivo1 archivo2
```

pero no tengo exito,
también con

```
join -t , archivo1 archivo2
```

y obtengo un archivo como el siguiente:

```
 1,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,CC1,I,,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,SRR9831335
1,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,CC1,I,,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,SRR9831337
1,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,CC1,I,,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,SRR9831339
121,7,6,8,8,6,37,1,CC121,II,,7,6,8,8,6,37,1,SRR9831336
129,90,24,155,189,117,244,66,ST129,L.,welshimeri,90,24,155,189,117,244,66,H38
4,1,2,12,3,2,5,3,CC4,I,,1,2,12,3,2,5,3,AW73
599,70,80,30,33,45,240,68,ST599,L.,innocua,70,80,30,33,45,240,68,AW71
689,8,6,8,6,1,37,1,CC689,II,,8,6,8,6,1,37,1,AW72
876,125,1,1,1,3,1,3,CC1,I,,125,1,1,1,3,1,3,SRR9831338
ST,abcZ,bglA,cat,dapE,dat,ldh,lhkA,CC,Lineage,,abcZ,bglA,cat,dapE,dat,ldh,lhkA,Sample
```

sin embargo cualdo quiero borrar las columnas no me lo permite

Al final de cuentas lo que deseo es que me imprima un archivo con las columnas 1,9,10,19

Comment: sería bueno que indicaras exactamente cómo debe ser la salida, no queda del todo claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar solo las columnas 1, 9, 10 y 19 de la salida del comando `join` de la pregunta se puede usar esto:

```bash
join -t , archivo1 archivo2 | cut -d , -f 1,9,10,19
```

Salida:

```
1,SRR9831337,3,
1,SRR9831339,3,
121,SRR9831336,7,
129,H38,90,welshimeri
4,AW73,1,
599,AW71,70,innocua
689,AW72,8,
876,SRR9831338,125,
ST,Sample,abcZ,
```

El comando `cut` sirve para extraer secciones de cada línea. La opción `-d ,` sirve para establecer una coma como delimitador en lugar del delimitador predeterminado (tabulación). La opción `-f 1,9,10,19` sirve para establecer los campos que se quieren extraer. Recibe una lista separada por comas de rangos, en el ejemplo se pasan 4 rangos y cada uno selecciona un único campo determinado por su posición (comenzando en 1).

Una explicación detallada de las partes de este comando se puede ver [aquí](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=join+-t+%2C+archivo1+archivo2+%7C+cut+-d+%2C+-f+1%2C9%2C10%2C19).